# Magento 1.8 search issue

Tags: search

The search function does not work properly, for instance when I search for SKM 500-965 it does not show that product and shows other products but the product SKM 500-965 exists.

I have disabled search in attributes for all of them except the product name and manufacturer

Website link: http://aes-audio.com/index.php

Search term:SKM 500-965 or Sennheiser SKM 500-965

Please advise how can I make the search accurate for when user search for a product it shows that product only.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to improve the default Magento search by:

1. Disabling the search option for most of the attributes and enabled those need only ( title and  manufacture)
2. And system->Catalog -> Catalog search and change Search Type to "Full Text" which helped a lot to improve the search results.